# Using Moq with EntityFramework graphdiff

Tags: entity-framework, moq, graphdiff

I have just added GraphDiff in an existing Entity Framework solution which is utilizing Moq framework for testing.
All my tests that are using Moq in insert and update methods are now failing since method **_context.UpdateGraph** throws following exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
GraphDiff on GitHub
https://github.com/refactorthis/GraphDiff

UpdateGraph extension method:
https://github.com/refactorthis/GraphDiff/blob/develop/GraphDiff/GraphDiff/DbContextExtensions.cs

How should you hookup Moq with GraphDiff?

Comment: You should include more information about the inner exceptions, or perhaps use the sorce code of GrpahDiff instead of the assembly to guess where the error comes from

Comment: Edited the answer with more info about GraphDif fand UpdateGraph extension method

Comment: Mocking entityframework is a pain. You need to mock ObjectContext as well as DbContext. GraphDiff uses ObjectContext. I tried but ended up using nuget Effort instead https://effort.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had this problem as well. This is how we solved it.

So this is in the IContext interface:

```
T UpdateGraph<T>(T entity, Expression<Func<IUpdateConfiguration<T>, object>> mapping = null) where T : class, new();

DbEntityEntry<TEntity> Entry<TEntity>(TEntity entity) where TEntity : class;
        DbEntityEntry Entry(object entity);

        DbContextConfiguration Configuration { get; }
```

This is in the base context:

```
 public virtual T UpdateGraph<T>(T entity, Expression<Func<IUpdateConfiguration<T>, object>> mapping = null) where T : class, new()
        {
            return null;
        }
```

and

```
private ObjectContext ObjectContext
        {
            get { return (this as IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext; }
        }
```

And this is in the actual concrete context:

```
public override T UpdateGraph<T>(T entity, Expression<Func<IUpdateConfiguration<T>, object>> mapping = null) // where T : class, new()
        {
            return DbContextExtensions.UpdateGraph<T>(this, entity, mapping);
        }
```

and

```
private ObjectContext ObjectContext
        {
            get { return (this as IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext; }
        }
```